# FreeBSD sed error editing files in place

Tags: linux, bash, sed, freebsd

Getting an error, trying edit file in place using in `sed` using FreeBSD

> sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin

```
# Hello World Program in Bash Shell
# This is a Linux Machine
#cat /proc/version
#Linux version 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 22:06:11 UTC 2015
echo "Hello World!" 
FILE=new.txt
FOO=/var/foo
VAR=/var

sed -i.tmp '/LD_LIBRARY_PATH={$stdlib}/a\'$'\n''LD_32_LIB_PATH='"$FOO"'\nldd '"$VAR"'' $FILE
```

Am trying to run the `sed` in-place append after a search pattern which is working fine in a RedHat Linux machine.

I am trying to run the same command in a FreeBSD machine(details `FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p2 FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p2 #0: Fri Jan 14 11:35:15 EST 2011` ) for which I am getting the above mentioned error.

Doesn't FreeBSD support an in-place replace from stdin?

Comment: Post the pattern, not following blind links...

Comment: Are you trying `some-command | sed -i ...` ?

Comment: How exactly is replacing stdin in-place supposed to work?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't appear to have sed reading from stdin. Are you sure you've posted exactly what you're running on the freebsd system?

Comment: The one I have posted is the same command I am trying to run in my freeBSD machine, for which I am getting the error shown in the description.

Comment: Probably `FILE` is unset. (or OP did some mistake in upper-case/lower-case of the variable name). Hence it expanded to empty string. Thus, `sed` expects something on `stdin`.

Comment: man sed inn your environement bu if ì`is available (seems not in FreeBSD) it take next argument as extension and you write without space separator before `.tmp`. Also, not sure your single quoted command is realy what you want with varaible inside (that will not be interpreted at sed runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On FreeBSD `tcsh` is the standard shell, not `bash`.

Setting variables in `tcsh` is done with `set`, not with a simple `=`.
So the `FILE` variable is unset when you run this script, and it tries to edit standard input.

The `-i` flag creates a backup of an in-place edited file. This makes no sense in the context of a stream like stdin. Hence the error message.